# thermal paste on GPU PCIe connector and inside motherboard's PCIe slot

Tags: gpu, thermal-paste

I took my pc to the repair shop to change the AIO cooler for my CPU. Apparently the tech dropped some thermal paste on my GPU pins while I wasn't around, amd when I got home I noticed thermal paste on my GPU.

I tried to clean it with alcohol, the GPU pins looks clean but there's still some thermal paste on the motherboard PCI that I couldn't clean

After cleaning it I tried to play some games to test but everything seems normal.

I have images of the GPU below - is there anything that I need to worry about?
[image: the GPU pins]
[image: the motherboard PCI]

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to clean the thermal paste thoroughly from the card and the socket.  Use alcohol and wipe it up till its gone.  Use a cotton swab to get into the socket.  If everything is working, you should be fine, but its easier to clean it up while its still wet and not dried and hard.  However, if you leave it there, debris like dust and hair will adhere to it and could cause problems later.